# Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON. and request.location = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocode

```
if Rails.env.development?
      @current_location_geo = Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first
    else
      @current_location_geo = request.location
    end
    if !@current_location_geo.nil? && @current_location_geo.ip == "127.0.0.1"
      @departure_currency_code= "AUD"
      @departure_currency_name= ["Australian Dollar(AUD $)","AUD"]
    else
      @country = Country.new(request.location.data["country_code"].to_s)
      @country_code = @country.currency.code
    end
end
```

i am getting **request.location nil**. i tried to add timeout in configuration but it not helped for me.

error in **production mode** as **"Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON."**

and when i traced it i got request.location as nil.

my geocoder version is (1.2.6).

Answer (score 1):

**config/initalizers/geocoder.rb**

```
Geocoder.configure(
 timeout: 10,
 ip_lookup: :telize   
)
```

Source: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/777

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just have no available action points to access to selected geo services. For me it was too small amount of available requests to `Google` geo services. I just increated it by registering on `Google` application serivces, and putting into config Google API key. For services, which determine `Geo` position by `IP`, it was recommended `:telize` since it does not have any request quotas currently by previous answerer. I also advice you to see into side of local IP storage to resovle them to Geo position, like `:geoip2`, and `:maxmind_local`. So your geoconfig will be like follows:

**config/initalizers/geocoder.rb:**

```
Geocoder.configure(                             
  lookup: :google,                                                 
  ip_lookup: :geoip2,                                                              
  maxmind_local: {
    package: :city                
  },                                                       
  geoip2: {
    file: File.join('vendor/share', 'GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
  },             
  google: {                        
    timeout: 20,
    use_https: true,                                                               
    api_key: ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']                                                 
  },       
}
```

*NOTE:* It seems that `:telize` service currently isn't properly working, returning: `Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON`.

Please refer to all options to configure goe services on [geocoder's README](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).